# Translating VB script NoShowAttr to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, catia

I am working with Catia V5 at the moment, and need to translate a code snippet written in what I believe is VB Script to VBA.

Specifically, I have the following snippet which I am stuck on at the moment:

```
oSelection1.VisProperties.SetShow(INFITF.CatVisPropertyShow.catVisPropertyNoShowAttr)
```

Currently when I run this code there is an Runtime Error (#424), stating that I need to define an object. oSelection1 is defined as a Selection.

Could anyone point me in the right direction here? I am very new to VBA so I apologize if this is a rookie question.

Comment: Why do you think in was VBScript, and what is `INFITF`?

Comment: `Selection` is not a valid Object type.  You *could* `Dim oSelection1 As Object` to keep it generic, but you would be better working out what the *actual* Object type is

Comment: Don't think that anyone will help, unless you show more code.

Comment: I believe it is VB Script based on the amount of googling and scanning of other code snippets I've done. I previously defined the selection as follows: `Set oSelection1 = o_Catia.ActiveDocument.Selection`. If I define it as `Dim oSelection1 As Object`, then the next line: `oSelection1.Clear` throws an error (#91).

Comment: @najusten I assume you've replaced `Set oSelection1 = ...` with `Dim oSelection1 As Object`. You should have added `Dim oSelection1 As Object` in front of the `Set oSelection1 = ...`. That still does not answer why you think it was VBScript (and not VBA to begin with) and, more importantly, what is `INFITF`.

Comment: VBScript is legal VBA.

Comment: @Mark [VBScript Features not in Visual Basic for Applications](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/f65b4a7c-eb8c-47f1-ba36-16ad8793026d.asp)

Comment: I have the help file. The code snippert is legal VBA or VBScript. And is also legal VB.NET. Help file is downloadable here http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

Comment: @Mark You didn't say anything about this code snippet. You said that any VBScript is legal VBA, that is not true.

Comment: What else would I be talking about.

Comment: [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. Otherwise it's not possible to help you.

Comment: Please check CATIA help file in your CATIA installation folder, is called v5automation.chm , see image below what you need to search in that file. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YauAn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YauAn.png)

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback! I do not have access to the downloadable help documentation you posted right now, but I will look at that as soon as I get the chance. I tried creating a new Module in Catia, and recording a Macro during which I hide the selected entity - `oSelection1.VisProperties.SetShow 1` achieves this. I hope these snippets accomplish the same task..?

Comment: That looks like it came from of a VB.NET application not VBSCript.  1. In VB.NET the value of the enumeration would be fully qualified (as it is here) and 2. Parentheses are used for a subroutine call, but without the CALL keyword.